# show on hover over a menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, opacity

I know this is a long time in the makin' and there have been previous answers similar / kind of, but I am really struggling to get the sibling to change opacity or visibility on hover event.

i know i must be doing something wrong but cant figure it out :( 
for the css - i just add either opacity:0 or visibility: collapsed to start with.

the code is:

```
 header#home
    .navbar
        nav
            ul.firstmenu
                li 
                    a(href="#home") welcome
                li
                    a(href="#about")  about me
                li.submenu
                    a(href="#portfolio")  portfolio

                li 
                    a(href="#social") social
                li 
                    a(href="#contact") contact

            ul.secondmenu
                li
                    a(href="/projects/randomQuote/index.html") random quote
```

and the js is:

```
$(".submenu").hover( function(){

    $(this).parent().siblings(".secondmenu").css("opacity","1")
}, function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings(".secondmenu").css("opacity","0")
})
```

Comment: Can you possibly re-state the problem and desired outcome, if not recreate it on CodePen or jsFiddle, etc? You can even fork & update this one I created: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyEdzQ .
Also, when hovering over the list item with a class of `submenu`, what is the expected behavior of the rest of the elements?

Comment: I've updated the CodePen to (I think?) reflect your intended result.

Comment: idea is - navigation stays fixed , on hover of submenu, a new navigation apears under the main one, on click of submenu, page is directed to the #id lower on the page....  thanks a lot i was doing the same similar thing somehow it will not show under, I will do a codepen tomorrow and paste the link here

Comment: http://codepen.io/JohnMica/pen/Pbwega here is the pen - however it seems not to work :( must be a css thing maybe ?

Comment: It works. If I actually linked jQuery it would have worked :) Thanks again